# Fuel hose leak after inactive for a while

Tags: fuel-system, mitsubishi, old-cars

Car was sitting for a while (3 months) in severe heat, this pipe cracked due to age, heat and being dry. It works fine but is leaking quite badly.

What is the type of piping required here? Would I just ask for standard fuel piping from a car shop or would it have to be specialised? I notice I can just unclip and replace the tubing and reclip.

Any worries I should have on this.

**The car is a 1984 Mitsubishi Colt GL (AU)**

[image]

[image]

Comment: I wouldn't drive a car with a leaking fuel line *at all*. The risk of fire and complete incineration of the car is too high, in my opinion.

Comment: Yes. Neither would I. I don't drive it. "It works fine" means it turns over, drives and isn't leaking prior to running.

I am not driving it though. I have a second car.

IN the time that I've noticed this hose, (and I notice this stuff instantly), it's been turned on once. And that was to check if the car runs (it does, but the hose leaked).

Answer (score 2):

Yep any rubber fuel hose of the same diameter will do the job - parts stores usually have reels of the stuff and will sell you whichever length you require.

If you aren't sure on the diameter (they do vary from car to car) some pipes will have it marked on them but given the age and condition of that pipe it may not be legible (even if it was there in the first place) you can just take it in have them match it.

Answer (score 1):

If the engine is carbureted, normal fuel injection hose will work.  If it has fuel injection, you will want fuel injection rated fuel hose.  Fuel injection hose also has special clips to provide more clamping force.

Comment: An early 80s car wouldn't have any fuel injection I'd think.

Comment: @insidesin looking at the pic it's a *Saturn* engine which is a carburetor setup IIRC

Comment: @insidesin unlikely that it is fuel injection, but not unheard of.  Dodge first started using fuel injection somewhere around 83/84.  I can't see the image to verify what you have since I am at work currently.  Wanted to make sure that there is a distinction for fuel injection hose since normal fuel hose will rupture in a fuel injection setup.

Comment: I have an original owners manual for the car (amazing) and I'll read it it before doing any work.